# Angular js Mean stack using mysql Controller Error

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I'm a complete Newbie, please help! :)

I am trying to access /products page and no data is being returned due to this error : Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ProductsController' is not a function, got undefined. I am using https://github.com/jpotts18/mean-stack-relational

public/js/app.js

```
angular.module('mean', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.route', 'mean.system', 'mean.articles', 'mean.products']);

angular.module('mean.system', []);
angular.module('mean.articles', []);
angular.module('mean.products', []);
```

public/js/config.js

```
'use strict';
//Setting up route
angular.module('mean').config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/articles', {
            templateUrl: 'views/articles/list.html'
        }).
        when('/articles/create', {
            templateUrl: 'views/articles/create.html'
        }).
        when('/articles/:articleId/edit', {
            templateUrl: 'views/articles/edit.html'
        }).
        when('/articles/:articleId', {
            templateUrl: 'views/articles/view.html'
        }).
        when('/products', {
            templateUrl: 'views/products/list.html',
            controller: 'ProductsController'
        }).
        when('/products/create', {
            templateUrl: 'views/products/create.html'
        }).
        when('/products/:productId/edit', {
            templateUrl: 'views/products/edit.html'
        }).
        when('/products/:productId', {
            templateUrl: 'views/products/view.html'
        }).
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/index.html'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }
]);

//Setting HTML5 Location Mode
angular.module('mean').config(['$locationProvider',
    function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
    }
]);
```

public/controllers/product.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('mean.products').controller('ProductsController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Products', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, Global, Products) {
    $scope.global = Global;

    $scope.create = function() {
        var product = new Products({
            title: this.title,
            content: this.content
        });

        product.$save(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $location.path("products/" + response.id);
        });

        this.title = "";
        this.content = "";
    };

    $scope.remove = function(product) {
        if (product) {
            product.$remove();  

            for (var i in $scope.products) {
                if ($scope.products[i] === product) {
                    $scope.products.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $scope.product.$remove();
            $location.path('products');
        }
    };

    $scope.update = function() {
        var product = $scope.product;
        if (!product.updated) {
            product.updated = [];
        }
        product.updated.push(new Date().getTime());

        product.$update(function() {
            $location.path('products/' + product.id);
        });
    };

    $scope.find = function() {
        Products.query(function(products) {
            $scope.products = products;
        });
    };

    $scope.findOne = function() {
        Products.get({
            productId: $routeParams.productId
        }, function(product) {
            $scope.product = product;
        });
    };
    }]);
```

public/views/products/list.html

```
<section data-ng-controller="ProductsController" data-ng-init="find()">
        <ul class="products unstyled">
            <li data-ng-repeat="product in products">
                <span>{{product.updatedAt | date:'medium'}}</span> /
                <span>{{product.user.name}}</span>
                <h2><a data-ng-href="#!/products/{{product.id}}">{{product.stockCode}}</a></h2>
                <div>{{product.price}}</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h1 data-ng-hide="!products || products.length">No products yet. <br> Why don't you <a href="/#!/products/create">Create One</a>?</h1>
    </section>
```

Comment: Are you including `<script src="public/controllers/product.js"></script>` in your main HTML file? Also, you should really use the `controller` property in your route configurations instead of `ng-controller`

Comment: Phill! Thanks man! Thats cleared that error and presented me with a new one! :)